# Data transformation: new min, max and mean

Tags: linear-transformations, transformation, data-analysis, data-structure

I have a dataset of 31 values, of which the $min = -0,8,\  max = 11, 1$ and $mean = 5,0$.

Is there a way to transform these data to a $\text{new} \ minimum (0.3),  \ \text{new} \ maximum (11.4)$ and $\text{new} \  mean (5.3)$?

Thanks!

```
6,7
4,9
4,5
3,0
4,6
1,9
2,7
4,0
2,3
6,4
7,6
6,2
6,7
6,3
11,1
9,1
8,3
8,3
4,5
5,6
5,6
5,9
4,4
5,9
2,4
0,7
1,0
-0,8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a quadratic equation to change every value in your dataset from $x_i$ to $y_i= a \cdot x_i^2+b \cdot x_i+ c$. The equation for the new minimum would then be $$0.3 = a \cdot (-0.8)^2+b \cdot (-0.8) + c\tag{1}$$
The equation for the new maximum would be $$11.4 = a \cdot (11.1)^2+b \cdot (11.1) + c \tag{2}$$
And the equation for the new mean would be $$5.3 = \frac{1}{31}\sum_{i=1}^{31} (a \cdot x_i^2+b \cdot x_i + c)$$
or
$$5.3 = a \cdot \frac{1}{31}\sum_{i=1}^{31} x_i^2+b \cdot (5.0) + c \tag{3}$$
Assuming equations $1$, $2$ and $3$ are linearly independent you could work out the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.